# How to remove only certain items within a column that has multiple words listed in cell

Tags: sql-server

## sql-server

From my column, I only want to "exclude" certain content from the cell.

Example 1:

```
select 
    owner
where
    owner not in ('LLC');
```

I'm trying to get the LLC excluded from: "`16 SE 2ND STREET LLC`"
Seems to only work if I want to removed the entire row from the data set, which I don't.

Example 2:

```
select 
    owner
where
    owner not in ('&');
```

I'm trying to only exclude anywhere in the column that has the & (ampersand)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SELECT <column-expression>...` part of the query to manipulate values ("projection"). The `WHERE` part to filter rows, not values. (the logical evaluation order of a `SELECT` query is actually `FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER BY`, so the `SELECT` part is not evaluated first despite being the first keyword.

A quick way would be to use `REPLACE( owner, 'LLC', '' )`, but this would also replace "`LLC`" located elsewhere in the string:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE( [owner], 'LLC', '' ) AS [owner],
    ...
FROM
    tableName
```

Alternatively, you could use `CASE WHEN` to only remove `LLC` if it's at the end of the string:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN SUBSTRING( [owner], LEN( [owner] ) - 4, 4 ) = ' LLC' THEN
            SUBSTRING( [owner], 1, LEN( [owner] ) - 4 )
        ELSE
            [owner]
    END AS [owner],
    ...
FROM
    tableName
```